# What tools are there for debugging/stepping through a regular expression?

Tags: regex, debugging

While there are many good online and offline tools for testing regular expressions, I have yet to find a tool (besides [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)) that lets me see the steps that the regular expression engine takes to find a match (or to find that there is no match, for that matter.)

Does anyone know of any tools that do this? The reason I have initially excluded [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is because it's commercial and I would prefer to look over my options before I decide to pay for it.

To make it clearer what I want, here is a screenshot from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) (from their home page):
http://img166.imageshack.us/img166/1272/debug.png

Comment: The screenshot has disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps RegexCoach offers what you're looking for...

http://weitz.de/regex-coach/

Comment: Thanks, but I already have RegexCoach installed. It does have simple step-by-step functionality, but it's very hard to compare the performances between different regular expressions using it. Also, it does not support certain regular expression extensions available in PCRE.

Answer (score 5):

In Perl you can always just [`use re 'debug';`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?re) or [`use re 'debugcolor';`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?re)

For example if you enter this into Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use re 'debug';

# using the same strings as the question's image for reference:

my $str = 'Even if I do say so myself: "RegexBuddy is awesome"';
$str =~ /(Regexp?Buddy is (awful|acceptable|awesome))/;
```

This is what you get out:

```
Compiling REx "(Regexp?Buddy is (awful|acceptable|awesome))"
Final program:
   1: OPEN1 (3)
   3:   EXACT <Regex> (6)
   6:   CURLY {0,1} (10)
   8:     EXACT <p> (0)
  10:   EXACT <Buddy is > (14)
  14:   OPEN2 (16)
  16:     EXACT <a> (18)
  18:     TRIEC-EXACT[cw] (29) # this is a new feature in Perl 5.10
          <wful> 
          <cceptable> 
          <wesome> 
  29:   CLOSE2 (31)
  31: CLOSE1 (33)
  33: END (0)

anchored "Regex" at 0 floating "Buddy is a" at 5..6 (checking floating) minlen 19 
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "(Regexp?Buddy is (awful|acceptable|awesome))" against 'Even if I do say so myself: "RegexBuddy is awesome"'
Found floating substr "Buddy is a" at offset 34...
Found anchored substr "Regex" at offset 29...
Starting position does not contradict # /^/m...
Guessed: match at offset 29

Matching REx "(Regexp?Buddy is (awful|acceptable|awesome))" against 'RegexBuddy is awesome"'
  29 <'lf: "'> <RegexBuddy>  |  1:OPEN1(3)
  29 <'lf: "'> <RegexBuddy>  |  3:EXACT <Regex>(6)
  34 <Regex> <Buddy is a>    |  6:CURLY {0,1}(10)
                                  EXACT <p> can match 0 times out of 1...
  34 <Regex> <Buddy is a>    | 10:  EXACT <Buddy is >(14)
  43 <y is > <'awesome"'>    | 14:  OPEN2(16)
  43 <y is > <'awesome"'>    | 16:  EXACT <a>(18)
  44 < is a> <'wesome"'>     | 18:  TRIEC-EXACT[cw](29)
  44 < is a> <'wesome"'>     |      State:    2 Accepted:    0 Charid:  2 CP:  77 After State:    3
  45 < is aw> <'esome"'>     |      State:    3 Accepted:    0 Charid:  7 CP:  65 After State:   10
  46 < is awe> <'some"'>     |      State:   10 Accepted:    0 Charid:  b CP:  73 After State:   11
  47 < is awes> <'ome"'>     |      State:   11 Accepted:    0 Charid:  c CP:  6f After State:   12
  48 < is aweso> <'me"'>     |      State:   12 Accepted:    0 Charid:  d CP:  6d After State:   13
  49 < is awesom> <'e"'>     |      State:   13 Accepted:    0 Charid:  7 CP:  65 After State:   14
  50 < is awesome> <'"'>     |      State:   14 Accepted:    1 Charid:  3 CP:   0 After State:    0
                                    got 1 possible matches
                                    only one match left: #3 <wesome>
  50 < is awesome> <'"'>     | 29:  CLOSE2(31)
  50 < is awesome> <'"'>     | 31:  CLOSE1(33)
  50 < is awesome> <'"'>     | 33:  END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "(Regexp?Buddy is (awful|acceptable|awesome))"
```

*( Note: I changed some parts of the output, so that it would highlight better )*

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite as powerful as RegexBuddy, but it's a simple online interface: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

You can mouse-over parts of your expression and it will tell you what it's doing. Very basic, but it can really save time when you do something stupid.

Answer (score 2):

[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) has the best graphical approach I've seen out there. It basically shows you what a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) diagram would look like for the given regular expression, has basic highlighting for the match, and has a slider at the bottom that lets you step through the match and DFA diagram step-by-step:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [CodVerter regex tester](https://codverter.com/src/regextester) Online regex tester to validate regular expression patterns.
 Editor is updating while typing and flags can be changed as desired.

Work can be saved local or to the cloud for further editing through the advanced repositories manager in the user account. when saving to the cloud you can generate a link to share your work with anyone.

*IP regex pattern example from CodVerter`s regex tester*
[image]

If you need more sophisticated tool for multiple regex patterns Try [CodVerter multiple regex patterns scanner](https://codverter.com/src/regexscanner)

Here is a short [tutorial](https://codverter.com/blog/articles/tutorials/20181204-multiple-regex-pattern-scanner-help.html) about this tool

(Full Disclosure: I am one of the developers of CodVerter)

Answer (score -1):

That's probably so because it should not matter how the regex engine finds a match. The screenshot of RegexBuddy makes me want to use another regexp matcher, as there should not be a need to do backtracking.

Normally, you would translate the regular expression into an [nondeterministic finite automaton (NFA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_state_machine) or a [deterministic finite automaton (DFA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), which can handle regular expressions without backtracking.

That being said, the only free tool for creating and testing regular expressions I know of is [pyreb](http://www.nongnu.org/pyreb/).

Comment: Yes, I've seen some examples of it (http://osteele.com/tools/reanimator/), but if I'm stuck with, say, PCRE, then I would like to be able to make sure I don't miss something that puts it into a backtracking extravaganza.

Comment: Okay, after reading http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000488.html it seems that regexp engines are indeed using backtracking, mostly to support groups. Sorry for my misleading post.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid =)

Comment: Actually in this particular example, it is possible to match without backtracking. Perl's regex engine, as of 5.10, uses [Trie optimization](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Regular-expressions-optimisations) to [accomplish this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144472).